# (Error 91 : object variable or with block variable not set) Error in declaring and accessing global variable in Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: visual-studio, vba, adodb

I am designing a login form. I have done global declaration in in a module:

```
   Global db  As ADODB.Connection
   Global rs  As ADODB.Recordset
   Global tot As Integer

   Public Sub access_connector()
   Set db = New ADODB.Connection
    db.Provider = "Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0"
    db.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    db.Open App.Path & "\data.mdb"
  End Sub
```

And in the form's code window :

```
   Private Sub Command1_Click()
   db.Open
   Set rs = db.Execute("SELECT * FROM Login Where UserName='" _
       & txtusername.Text & "'")
   If txtpassword = "" And txtusername = "" Then
      MsgBox "Login not possible"
   Else
   If Not rs.EOF() Then
      If (rs(1) = txtpassword.Text) Then
          MsgBox "Login Successful"
      Else
          MsgBox "Login not success"
      End If
   Else
      MsgBox "EOF Reached"
  End  If
 End If
 db.Close
 End Sub
```

But when I click on Login button the following error occurs : 
**Error 91 : object variable or with block variable not set**

Actually I think (may not be true) it is not able to recognize "db" and "rs" objects, as while debugging "db.open" is highlighted.

Can anyone please solve this problem. I would be very thankful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the call to access_connector?  It is probably missing so sure, db is still nothing.

Comment: Thanks a lot....i hvnt called access_connector. Now the prblm is solved...Thanx again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the name of your "db" variable to "conn" to emphasize the fact that it's a connection, not a database.  Then, you should open the connection when you need it, in the form.  You have to specify the database in the form, as you haven't declared a database variable earlier.  Probably you should re-think the global ADODB variables and just include them in your form code, but I'm not sure about that.

```
Global conn As ADODB.Connection
Global tot As Integer

Public Sub access_connector()
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Provider = "Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0"
conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

access_connector
conn.Open App.Path & "\data.mdb"
Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM Login Where UserName='" & txtusername.Text & "'")
If txtpassword = "" And txtusername = "" Then
    MsgBox "Login not possible"
Else
    If Not rs.EOF() Then
        If (rs(1) = txtpassword.Text) Then
            MsgBox "Login Successful"
        Else
            MsgBox "Login not success"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "EOF Reached"
    End If
End If
conn.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Reading Hans' comment, you could also leave the access_connector sub as you have - although I would call the variable "conn" to avoid confusion, and then call it from the form.  Since you have dp.open in both places I wasn't sure how much of it you want to be global.

Comment: Thanks a lot....i hvnt called access_connector. Now the prblm is solved...Thanx again.